# How can I make my calendar occupy the half of my website? using Shadcn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, shadcnui

I'm trying to create a scheduling appointment system, I'm trying to make the calendar occupy the half of my page, but even though I tried to increase it's height and width, it doesn't change anything.

[image]

Home.tsx

```
import { Calendar } from '@/components/ui/calendar'
import React from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='w-full  px-8'>
      <div className='flex gap-x-2'>
          <div className='flex-1 h-[650px] w-full  bg-blue-200'>
            <Calendar className='h-full w-full' />
          </div>
          <div className='flex-1'>2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You'll need to see what CSS rules are used internally and adjust those as well with overrides.

Comment: Oh, I need edit the actual Calendar Component?

Comment: No. You just need to write CSS rules that change how it looks, and apply those after so they have precedence. Look around with your CSS inspector at the rule names used, or the class/ID attributes you can key on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `Home.tsx` as per bellow:

```js
import { Calendar } from "@/components/ui/calendar";
import React from "react";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="w-full  px-8">
      <div className="flex gap-x-2">
        <div className="flex-1 h-[650px] w-full  bg-blue-200">
          <Calendar
            className="h-full w-full flex"
            classNames={{
              months:
                "flex w-full flex-col sm:flex-row space-y-4 sm:space-x-4 sm:space-y-0 flex-1",
              month: "space-y-4 w-full flex flex-col",
              table: "w-full h-full border-collapse space-y-1",
              head_row: "",
              row: "w-full mt-2",
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more details your can refer the docs [here](https://react-day-picker.js.org/basics/styling)